# MongoEngine: storing EmbeddedDocument in DictField

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine, nosql

I'm modelling a **MongoDB** database in MongoEngine for a web project. I want to store the data in a slightly unusual way to be able to efficiently query it later.

Our data in MongoDB looks something like this:

```
// "outer"
{  
  "outer_data": "directors",
  "embed": {
     "some_md5_key": { "name": "P.T. Anderson" },
     "another_md5_key": { "name": "T. Malick" },
     ...
   }
}
```

My first instinct was to model it like this in MongoEngine:

```
class Inner(EmbeddedDocument):
  name = StringField()

class Outer(Document):
  outer_data = StringField()
  embed = DictField(EmbeddedDocument(Inner))  # this isn't allowed but you get the point
```

In other words, what I essentially want is the same an storing an EmbeddedDocument in a ListField but rather in a DictField with dynamic keys for each EmbeddedDocument.

Example that *is allowed* with a ListField for reference:

```
class Inner(EmbeddedDocument):
  inner_id = StringField(unique=True)  # this replaces the dict keys
  name = StringField()

class Outer(Document):
  outer_data = StringField()
  embed = ListField(EmbeddedDocument(Inner))
```

I would prefer to have MongoEngine objects returned also for the nested "Inner" documents while still using a DictField + EmbeddedDocument (as dict "value"). How can I model this in MongoEngine? Is it even possible or do I have to naively place all data under a generic DictField?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem. The correct way to achieve this pattern is by making use of a [`MapField`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.MapField).

The corresponding model in MongoEngine looks like:

```
class Inner(EmbeddedDocument):
  name = StringField()

class Outer(Document):
  outer_data = StringField()
  embed = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Inner))
```

In MongoDB, all keys needs to be strings so there is no need to specify a "field type" for the keys in the `MapField`.

Comment: I tried this approach but while saving it gives me "The source SON object needs to be of type 'dict'". Do you have a solution for this will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: for me, embed was a list of dictionary. so, `embed = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Inner))` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In My case it is working without MapField

```
class Inner(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()

class Outer(Document):
    outer_data = StringField()
    embed = EmbeddedDocumentField(Inner)
```